# java action on multiple checkboxMenuItems at the same time

Tags: java

I'm working on a java project in NetBeans. I have put 5 checkboxMenuItems in 1 Menu (First Class) (see picture). Now I want to be able to check or uncheck multiple items at the same time. Meaning that I want to open the menu once, check and uncheck what I want & then use a function that looks which are selected or not. I know I can do 'actionPerformed' on each separate checkboxMenuItem, but that's not what I need here.

How should I handle this instead?

[image]

Comment: Swing class javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem

Comment: When you want the action to be fired?After the pop up dissapear? Or you want to call it manually?